# Alternative ways of Greyscaling a tif

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Currently I'm using ArcMap>Image Analysis>Greyscale function to greyscale an OS VectorMap tiff. This turns hill or housing colours into greyshades as expected & shown in the image below.

Is there a way to greyscale the image but remove the grey fill on block shading like houses, hillsides or roads?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Classify symbology as unique values. As long as the features you want to remove are all the same value, you can just change their color.